# CSS sprites not working in <li> items

Tags: html, css

I have a sprite-sheet with 4 social sprite buttons that I can't get to work as list items after many hours of researching.
Each sprite button should take up the same background-position as in the sprite-sheet. I have even tried setting each background-position: 0 0; without success.
 Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: My sprite-sheet]

```css
.s-1-facebook,
.s-2-tweet,
.s-3-google,
.s-4-email {
  <!--background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpoaF.png');-->
  background-image: url('images/sprites.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -16px;
  position: relative;
}
.s-1-facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
.s-2-tweet {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-position: -32px 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
.s-3-google {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-position: -72px 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
.s-4-email {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-position: -108px 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="s-1-facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-2-tweet">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Tweet"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-3-google">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-4-email">
    <a href="mailto:?subject=&body=:%20http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Email"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tips for using sprites in CSS

Let's take the [`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpoaF.png) you provided as example. The image has **140px** width and **32px** height.

Since we have 4 equally distributed icons in the image, we can assume that every icon will have **35px** width **(140 / 4)** and **32px** height.

In order to make the sprite work, we will have to assign those width/height values to an element of our choose, in your case, we will use the tag `a` inside  every `li`.

To change the icon shown in every class, we will use the CSS property [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

Since we already know that our sprite have 4 columns and 1 row, we will only need to use the `x` position (using factors of **35**).

## Example

```css
ul.social {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.social li {
  float: left;
}
ul.social a {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpoaF.png');
  width: 35px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.social li.s-2-tweet a {
  background-position: -35px 0;
}
ul.social li.s-3-google a {
  background-position: -70px 0;
}
ul.social li.s-4-email a {
  background-position: -105px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="social">
  <li class="s-1-facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-2-tweet">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Tweet"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-3-google">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="s-4-email">
    <a href="mailto:?subject=&body=:%20http%3A%2F%2F12phillipstreet.com" target="_blank" title="Email"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now that I am back in action again I will point out my careless mistake in not using the correct address of my "sprites image" that caused all my grief during this exercise.
I was using "background-image: url('images/sprites.png')' instead of "background-image: url('../images/sprites.png')" or including the full address.
While continually looking for more complex coding problems, I missed this simple one that was shown in both answers given. 
Thanks again for your invaluable help and I hope this simple lesson  may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment for the background image is using HTML comment tags which are invalid in CSS and causing your sprite image to fail. Remove that line and you can be on your way.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt help. The first answer worked best for me. Cheers

Comment: @JohnLucke What first answer? This is not how SO works. You upvote and accept answers indicating to everyone the solution and not leave things a mystery so others may learn.

Comment: @JohnLucke whenever it's possible, come back and mark the answer that helped you as the right answer or upvote the ones that gave you some light, so other users can benefit from it aswell.